# Why assigning the postfix operation not updating the value of a variable?

Tags: javascript

Today I see a weird result with the postfix and assignment operator which I was not expecting at all.

let say

```
let a = 10;
```

when we increment with postfix, it will result with the addition of `1` as follows

```
console.log( a++ );    // 10
console.log( a );      // 11
```

AFAIK `a++` is a postfix operation which means

- First, it will use the value(that's why `a++` returns `10`) and then
- update the value
- When we print the value, the value has been updated. That's why `a` returns `11`.

So far so good,

But when I assigned the postfix operation to a variable, it won't update the value.

```
a = a++;
console.log( a );     // 11
```

Though I was expecting the result to be 12. Why this result? Thanks in advance.

```js
let a = 10;
console.log(a++);
console.log(a);

a = a++;
console.log(a);
```

Comment: I thought maybe it would be because of the precedence of the `assignment` or `postfix` operator. But the precedence of `postfix` is greater than `assignment`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Comment: `a++` evaluates to the value of `a`, then increments `a`.  The original value of `a` is being re-assigned back to the variable after the increment occurs (because that is what the postfix expression evaluated to)

Comment: that means `b = b` and `b = b++` are both equal. 

Comment: Yes, that is what the postfix operator does.

Comment: @SebastianSimon yeah this answer my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does increment but if you breakdown the process,

Since the precedence of the postfix is greater than assignment

```
b = b++
```

Step 1 => Execute `b++` which returns b

Step 2 => Assign returned value to the b, i.e assign b to b

Now console.log show the same old value.

```
b = 10;
```

Step 1 => return 10 and increment to 11.
Step 2 => Since the returned value is 10, re assign the 10 to `a` which cause `console.log(a)` to show 10 as the value.